# Compatibility With GSM/GPRS A6

Tags: pi-zero-w

I'm working with an A06 V2 connected to a Pi zero. Using AT commands to send 
SMS functions correctly.
 I try to send MMS using CMMSXXXX commands There is problem. The first commande must by AT+CMMSINIT that return : +cme error 58 and all subsequent commands beginning by CMMS are ignored. 
Is this module (GSM/GPRS A6) Compatable with CMMS commands? Why CMMSINIT return cme error 58? what means 58 that in not referenced? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using `AT+CLAC` will get the device to output the commands that it understands. Hopefully that output will answer your question.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry This command CLAC does not exist in A6 AT Commands

Answer (score 0):

Well A6 A7 or A20 have not the capability To send MMS. ATCMMS* commands are not available. We have to use one carde whit SIM808 Module. Welcome to everyone that Can help me for this procedure. 
cme error 58 means : Invalid command line.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.